# Instance Group : remove autoscaling and set number of instances to 0

Tags: google-compute-engine, autoscaling, gce-instance-group

I have a requirement in which i have to stop instance group during night hours and then restart in the morning. Is there anyway I can stop instance group for few hours. From console i can change autoscaling to off and set number of instances to 0 but i cant find this option from the API. Please suggest

Comment: are you using Kubernetes ?

Comment: no i m not using Kubernetes

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
gcloud compute instance-groups managed stop-autoscaling NAME [--zone ZONE]
```

and

```
gcloud compute instance-groups managed set-autoscaling NAME \
    --max-num-replicas MAX_NUM_REPLICAS [--zone ZONE]
```

Note that `stop-autoscaling` will not bring down the number of instances to 0 for you, you need `set-autoscaling --max-num-replicas`.

The corresponding REST API is [InstanceGroupManagers: resize](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/instanceGroupManagers/resize).

Comment: I was looking for java api solution for this. I know gcloud command and console supports this.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/instanceGroupManagers/resize